Optimized DB Pagination for HTTP service
This is a back to basics questions for anyone who understands backend in depth.
The problem is simple i have http api
Eg: v1/foo?filter=F1&offset=100&limit=10 with following query parameters

limit
offset
filter

This api calls back into PG database on a standalone table with following columns

PK (Serial int)
Desc(text, not null)
Flags (text, not null)

I assume most optimised query for the above api is(with a index on flags col as well)
select * from table 
where Flags=${Filter}
offset ${offset}
limit ${limit}
order by PK

But if you look from DB Engine side its the worst query ever, DB Engine has to run the where clause across the entire table/index(assume rows above 10Million) then order it by PK and then limit and offset it.. which is the most inefficient thing... it kills the reason for having pagination on the API don't you think?
I mean it has to scan entire table/index filter the results for everything and just return a part of it and repeat this for all pages(while we feel we have implemented pagination for lesser load and strain on resources)
So then what does the correct answer looks like for pagination?
First we ask PG how many blocks/OS File is this table spread across, we then take one block per api request scan it with where filter condition and then return the results?
It has some side effects like null page response (where the block returned zero results for filtered criteria even though there might be more blocks to scan through which may have results)Its more like an iterator interface where server decides what the page size and offset should be before yielding.
This seems to be the best way to manage resources and really be true to definition of pagination (loose analogy of scanning through a book of sorts),
But here is the problem i see no database every supports such thing why?
Limit and Offset always felt like after thought where result is entirely compiled then they are applied...
Or there are other operators/ways to implement this simple requirement?
Or am i missing anything here?
Update:
People talk about Keyset pagination in comments which is a good way to cut the offset clause, but still fails to have endstop to the page which means server can work long untill it meets condition..
Eg: 1....10000000 I can say offset 100 limit 20000 which means >100 limit 20000 so untill it finds 20000 rows it will keep working..
Plus what i understand is pg creates the entire resultset first then applies limit which means it will still scan the entire index/table
This different from just take one file scanning it and returning results I think this makes server do only finite work thus being more predictable?

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

There are lots of methods to optimize pagination, from simply building a better index (Flags, PK) to key-set pagination to stateful connections.  Stackoverflow isn't really the forum for that discussion, and anyway you should start be reading what is already said on the topic which it doesn't seem like you have.

Ok @JGH, This is good alternate method instead of offset I can start my result from last record, but it still has the problem of not having a end stop.. vs what I defined in my example it has to be finite amount of work with a finite page..

@jjanes if you have reading material where you think this problem is solved please point me to them, Tell me what is the right forum to ask this into... apart everyone's reach on internet is different so stop assuming people have not read

Could you please share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved, the complete SQL query and the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query? All in plain text, as an update of your question. Right now we can only guess what is going on and make assumptions about it.

See also https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/

@FrankHeikens this question is an example of problems seen across lot of implementation, I am sure you can look at the examples if you want to construct the table.. but it's a simple thought experiment.. assumption is fine as long as solution is logically faster, eg Keystone pagination compared to offset query..

As @jjanes says (flags, pk) should do the trick. Please get the JSON plan and paste it in my site Check The Plan.

Oh... just noticed that Flags has the data type TEXT. Is this true? That may cause some indexing issues.

Your assumption is that something is slow. Reality might be very very different. We have done things in databases that would be impossible if you believe others. Reality is that it does its job within milliseconds. That's why I like to focus on real problems, not assumptions of potential problems.

@FrankHeikens , I am not sure are you saying "if it works then it works" this question is simple  BigO notation question Eg: even reading through index is N problem once your table crosses N into a large row count or RAM shrinks DB Engine will take erractic time to complete, so the question was shouldn't N be fixed number for the server to have deterministic query time.. if yes then how no sql operator gives the iterator interface and don't say cursor..

No, no cursors for me, no need for. Just a famous quote: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

...and the plan?

There are 4 types of pagination that we can choose from

Simple limit & offset
Pagination with HOLD cursors
Keyset pagination

Pro's and Con's are well documented at https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/ so wont do that again.

With CTID's   <--- New one

Pro's:

You don't need any special column or index for this to work
DB Engine is going to do a finite job with finite resources always, most important for huge tables and busy servers since most of the above methods keep on swapping mem pages in and out which is more like non-finite work to retrieve pages.(If you need time bound execution this methods fits well)
Utilizes existing pagination done by DB engine for efficient data keeping.

Con's:

It uses system column called CTID, so if things change in future versions of pg this method may not work.
Not stable pagination with Update, Delete, Vacuum operations (Eg: if a row which is already read in page 1 gets updated while we are paginating it may appear in last page again with updated values, simply repeat of data and can be solved to an extend with pk)
Possible null pages i.e: Page might return empty records but the next page can have more records.

How to do it:
Step1: Get the total number of pages from system table by
    Select relpages,relfilenode
FROM
    pg_class c
WHERE
    relname = 'Your_table_name'
ORDER BY relfilenode

Step2: Call for a finite search by
SELECT *
    FROM Your_table_name
    WHERE ctid BETWEEN '(PAGE_START,0)'::tid AND '(PAGE_END,65535)'::tid
    AND 'Add any more condition required'

voila!!
The idea is to tap into how PG manages data on files in blocks/pages of 8KB each such each page defined already which is memory mapped we can always calculate how much resources our query is going to take since we know how many pages we are asking it to read, which also bring in predictability in query times and saves us lot of indexing on other column cause we are in a finite table scan so we can have any conditions combined with it plus no additional column needed for sorting or oder-ing etc while paginating.
Example:
Create a table "hugedata"
CREATE TABLE hugedata (
pk SERIAL not null,
description text,
flags varchar(5) not null
);

Insert some hughe data:
INSERT INTO hugedata (flags)
SELECT substring((d::TEXT || '_' || (random() * 1000)::TEXT),0,5)
FROM generate_series(0,1000000,1) AS d(d);

Ask for how many pages and files is the table spread across
Select relpages,relfilenode
FROM pg_class c
WHERE relname = 'hugedata'
ORDER BY relfilenode

Choose a number of pages to scan through with any extra conditions and start paginating :)
SELECT *
FROM hugedata
WHERE ctid BETWEEN '(0,0)'::tid AND '(1000,65535)'::tid 
AND pk>5

